# why can't we set base currency per store in magento?

Tags: magento2, checkout, currency

This question is more on a confimation.

i have a problem on checking out via paypal because of magentos auto conversion of default currency to base currency. the solution i made is to make base currency visible in store config.

```
    <section id="currency">
        <group id="options">
            <label>Currency Options</label>
            <field id="base" translate="label comment" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1" canRestore="1">
                <label>Base Currency</label>
                <frontend_model>Magento\Directory\Block\Adminhtml\Frontend\Currency\Base</frontend_model>
                <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Locale\Currency</source_model>
                <backend_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Currency\Base</backend_model>
                <comment>
                    <![CDATA[Base currency is used for all online payment transactions. The base currency scope is defined by the catalog price scope ("Catalog" > "Price" > "Catalog Price Scope").]]>
                </comment>
            </field>
        </group>
    </section>
```

things looks good on my side. but i feel something is wrong with this approach. i think magento made this feature avaible on global and website scope only for a reason. can someone give me some feedbacks and suggestions on how to do this properly?

much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Base currency is on website level (or global), that is how Magento is built. You will not be able to fix this by just changing the scope of the variable in your system.xml.

To change this on a code level will probably require hundreds of overides and schema changes.